# How to translate 妙？

Tags: characters

I find the internet has these translations which are "wonderful" and "ingenious". I find the latter closer to the essence of the 妙。But I think something is amiss.

妙 has the meaning of subtlety in it and has the connotation that when you understand why it's "妙" then there is the feeling satisfaction. None of these subtle aspects is captured by "ingenious".

What is some good translation of the word 妙? I am thinking in the context of playing Go/Weiqi/Baduk.

Comment: Why can not use [subtle sense 1.3](https://www.lexico.com/definition/subtle) ?

Comment: I think 'wonderful' is a correct translation for 妙.

Comment: `None of these subtle aspects is captured by "ingenious".` This is incorrect, and you should ask this at English StackExchange.

Answer (score 3):

There is a *[Go Dictionary](https://senseis.xmp.net/?ChineseGoTerms)* that contains two terms that begin with 妙.

**妙手** which is defined:

> excellent move

and **妙着** [sic?] which is also defined:

> excellent move

Here 妙 is consistently translated “excellent.”

“Clever,” might also be a option.

Answer (score 3):

Agree - it’s hard to find a word to capture the subtle meaning of 妙. This is the beauty of Chinese. In some context, I think maybe we can also use “smart”.

Answer (score 2):

I play chess, so when I see a move that's particularly clever, I like to say it's beautiful. Many chess players also use this, such as [Kasparov](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6vYJyOGKCHE).

Answer (score 2):

妙 is an adjective used to express better than expected.
妙 is composed of 女 and 少, 少女means young girl, just one 妙 means wonderful.